# Intuitive explanation for expectiles

Tags: risk-management, value-at-risk, expected, expected-value

> I am looking for an intuitive explanation for **expectiles**.

Here is a link to a paper about expectiles:

[Bellini and Di Bernardino: Risk Management with Expectiles, European Journal of Finance, May 2015](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276935585_Risk_Management_with_Expectiles)

---

Definition of expectiles by paper above
[image]

---

Since ES lacks elicitability it seems that some researchers are moving on to expectiles.

Can anybody give an intuitve explanation for expectiles and what they represent.

This isn't 100% true but maybe one could argue that $ES_{97.5}$ is the equivalent to $VaR_{99}$. What would be the equivalent expectile?

Comment: Notice that $(X-x)_-=(x-X)_+$. So the expectile can be interpreted as the strike of a put and call option such that their prices are in proportion $q/(1-q)$ to one another, by condition (2). If the expectation is taken w.r.t. risk-neutral pricing measure of course.

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with risk neutral pricing. But I am not sure. As far as I understand q stands for quantile not the risk neutral probability.

Comment: I never said it did. I just gave a possible interpretation within the context of $\mathbb{E}$ being taken w.r.t. risk-neutral pricing measure. P.S. what definition of ES do you use?

Comment: True, thank you.

Comment: This is my definition of ES mean above corresponding VaR $ES_\alpha = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \int_\alpha^1 VaR_u(L)du$ the empirical version is mean of all observations above VaR

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No reply has been given so I wanted to at least give a visualisation of the expectiles.

[image]

Suppose the curvy dashed line in my picture represents a cumulative distribution function of some random variable X. Then blue part corresponds exactly to $\mathbb{E}[(X-x)_+]$, while the orange surface corresponds to $\mathbb{E}[(X-x)_-]$. In the picture $x=1$. Now if the proportion of the blue and orange surface is equal to $(1-q)/q$, then we can say that $x$ is the $q$-expectile for this distribution.

How does this connect to the expected shortfall? Well, the ES as you defined it is exactly the blue surface divided by $1-\alpha$ for the value of $\alpha$ such that $\text{VaR}_{\alpha}[X]=x$, i.e.

$$\mathbb{E}[(X-x)_+]=(1-\alpha)\text{ES}_{\alpha}[X] \; .$$

Comment: Thanks. That is the intuition I was looking for. The concept seems similar to Omega, a measure of return.

Comment: Indeed, Omega is the ratio of the blue and orange surfaces. So, setting the ratio to a fixed number determines a value $x$ and that's your expectile. So, expectile is the inverse function of Omega.

Answer (score 4):

That picture in the [other answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/38097/1870) is pretty slick (+1), so I will just add a note on why one can interpret the colors of those areas like that:

1. Blue:

Define $Y = (X-x)_+$. This is nonnegative r.v., so you can [take advantage of the formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13377/8336)

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_0^\infty [1-F_Y(y)] dy \tag{1}.
$$

where $F_Y$ is the cdf of $Y$. The image plots $F_X(x)$, the cdf of $X$, though. For any $y \ge 0$

\begin{align*}
F_Y(y) 
&= \mathbb{P}[Y \le y] \\
&= \mathbb{P}[(X-x)_+ \le y] \\
&= \mathbb{P}[(X-x)_+ \le y, \{X > x \}] + \mathbb{P}[(X-x)_+ \le y, \{X \le x \}] \\
&= F_X(y+x)
\end{align*}
Using a change of variables $t = y + x$, we get
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X-x)_+] = \int_0^\infty [1-F_X(y+x)] dy = \int_x^\infty [1-F_X(t)] dt.
$$
The last expression $\int_x^\infty [1-F_X(t)] dt$ is exactly the area of the blue region.

2. Orange:

Define $W = (X-x)_-$. This is also nonnegative, and we can take advantage of (1) again. The only additional bit is the identity mentioned by [@raskolnikov](https://quant.stackexchange.com/users/156/raskolnikov): $(X-x)_-=(x-X)_+$.

Let $w \ge 0$; then

\begin{align*}
F_W(w) 
&= \mathbb{P}[W \le w] \\
&= \mathbb{P}[(X-x)_- \le w] \\
&= \mathbb{P}[(x-X)_+ \le w, \{X > x \}] + \mathbb{P}[(x-X)_+ \le w, \{X \le x \}] \\
&= \mathbb{P}[X > x ] + \mathbb{P}[x - w \le X \le x] \\
&= 1- F_X(x-w) 
\end{align*}

After a change of variables you get the formula for the orange region:

$$
\mathbb{E}[(X-x)_-] = \int_{-\infty}^x F_X(t)dt.
$$